# Playlist null value return

Tags: spotify

I'm still developping a Spotify App, but I thinkg there is some bug in the API and they report it as a bug for me.

I make then the test with the tutorial app using the function "Get songs from a playlist URL", they are in the tutorial using also the callback function like this

```
var pl = models.Playlist.fromURI(playlist_url, function(playlist)
```

But even using the Callback function on first load there is some null value.

With my own playlist, I don't have the issue but with playlist from other users I got the issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anybody else get the issue ? Is there a way to report API bug ?

For those who want to test my playlist: http://open.spotify.com/user/gpsnail/playlist/6qhk1FhYKwyanNAu91GftW

Answer (score 0):

The Spotify Apps API 0.X is not longer supported. It might be the case that there was a bug and the data was being rendered before it was actually fetched. I would recommend you to use the newer version of the API, in which you can fetch the contents of a playlist doing:

```js
    require(['$api/models'], function(models) {

      var playlistURI = 'spotify:user:gpsnail:playlist:6qhk1FhYKwyanNAu91GftW';

      models.Playlist.fromURI(playlistURI)
        .load('tracks')
        .done(function(p) {
            p.tracks.snapshot()
            .done(
                function(snapshot) {
                    for (var i = 0, l = snapshot.length; i < l; i++) {
                       var track = snapshot.get(i);

                       // we print out some basic data from the track       
                       console.log(track.uri, track.name);
                    }
                })
            .fail(
                function(){
                    console.error('Error retrieving snapshot');
                });
        })
        .fail(function(){
            console.error('Error retrieving playlist information');
        });
    });
```

There is more information about how to upgrade to the [upgrade guide](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/upgrade-guide/1.0.0).